# Dragging pasteboard is nil when remote debugging from Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, remote-debugging, nspasteboard

I'm writing an app that needs to work in both 10.5 and 10.6 (We still have PPC machines). My development machine is 10.6.4 with Xcode 3.2.3, and I have a 10.5.8 machine with Xcode 3.1.2 on it.

I use remote debugging to test out the app on the 10.5.8 machine, and I've run into a problem with a Drag and Drop method that only occurs when remote debugging.

The `NSTableViewDelegate` method `- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard`
passes a nil NSPasteboard. This doesn't happen when running natively in 10.6.4 or 10.5.8.

I'm relatively new to Xcode and Objective-C, and completely new to the underpinnings of GDB and SSH, so I don't know what to do to find out what's causing this problem.

There's also some unusual messages in the console just before the app starts, not sure if it's related:

```
Loading program into debugger…
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
Program loaded.
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
unable to read unknown load command 0x22
run
[Switching to process 1548 local thread 0x1003]
Running…
```